Download eQTL data of one specific gene for all tissues from GTEx
I have a gene of interest, i.e, AhR. I want to download its eQTL data for all tissues from GTEx.
I find I cannot do it from GTEx Portal.
I guess it is required with using R code with GTEx APIs.
Am I right? can anyone help me with it?
